# Search for element using index in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

`['zero','one','two','three','four','five','six','seven','eight','nine']` I want to search for an element with index 4 in the array above. So 4 should return the word "four" because it is at index four. Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would simply use bracket notation like so:

```js
var array = ['zero','one','two','three','four','five','six','seven','eight','nine'];

console.log(array[4]);
```

The above snippet outputs 'four' to the console. For more information, see [MDN's Property accessors page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors).

Comment: Thank you. @Travis

Comment: No problem. If this is a satisfactory answer, go ahead and mark it answered.